# Client Server connection error running client class off the CMD but works fine with netcat command

Tags: java, connection, client-server

I have a server class, which extends Thread, waiting for a connection on port 8818:

```
public void run() {
        // Create our server and create / accept incoming connections
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPortNumber);
            while (true) {
                // Listen for incoming connections and craete connection with accept
                System.out.println("Waiting for client connection.... on localhost port " + serverPortNumber
                        + ". \n Client connect via netcat localhost 8818");

                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();// returns a client Socket object
                System.out.println("Conenction established with " + clientSocket);

                // Each new connection will be handled on a new thread and can run concurrenlty
                ManageMultipleConnections multipleConnections = new ManageMultipleConnections(this, clientSocket);
                clientList.add(multipleConnections);
                multipleConnections.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I if start up a CMD, and use netcat to make a connection as follows:

```
nc localhost 8818
```

A socket is returned from

```
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

The clientSocket is then added to MangeMultipleCOnnections class, which is also a thread.

```
 ManageMultipleConnections multipleConnections = new ManageMultipleConnections(this, clientSocket);
                        clientList.add(multipleConnections);
                        multipleConnections.start();
```

The ManageMultipleConeections then gets the input and outputstreams for the client and handles communication:

```
clientInput = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        clientoutput = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(clientoutput, true);
```

It all works as expected for a multiple chat server - client, where each client connection is established through netcat.

However, if I try to establish a connection with the severer on same localhost port 8818, by running a java client class on the CMD:

```
java testClient
```

The connection immediately shuts down once the serverSocket.accept() has executed.
The clientConnection class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // connects to a well know time server on port 13 and gets data back in tme

        Socket socket;

        String hostname;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            hostname = args[0];
        }else {
            hostname = "localhost";
        }


        try {
            System.out.println("Trying to connect to " + hostname + " on port " + 8818);
            socket = new Socket(hostname, 8818);
            System.out.println("Connected on " + socket.getInetAddress() + " " );
        }catch(UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Cant connect to " + hostname);
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The exception:

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Therefor I can no longer communicte to the client via the CMD.
Any input appreciated.

Furthger info:
The exceotion is thrown when here in the MangageMultipleConnections thread:

```
clientInput = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        clientoutput = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(clientoutput, true);

try {
            if (loginMessage == null) {
                clientoutput.write((message).getBytes());
            } else {
                clientoutput.write((message).getBytes());
                clientoutput.write((loginMessage).getBytes());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Which side is throwing this exception? Whichever it is, the peer is closing the connection without reading its input. This client for example, which doesn't even bother to close the socket either.

Comment: @user207421 see additional info, appears to be thrown when the try to write to the output stream

Comment: Yes, so it is all exactly as I already stated.